# Drools Business Central Workbench v8

Tags: drools

What happened to Business Central Workbench on v8? There's nothing on the download page, and I can't mention it being removed/deprecated in the changelogs:
https://www.drools.org/download/download.html

The quay repository also has 7.73.0 as the latest image.
Is Drools still supported by RedHat or is it an Upstream for IBM DM now?

I was expecting the Business Central Workbench to be available for download on Wildfly, or something else.
However, there is no mention of it in v8, nor can I find any download/container for it.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Business Central is retired in favor of VS Code Kogito Extension.

https://docs.drools.org/8.38.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/migration-guide/index.html#business-central_migration-guide